# my code work at eclipse but does not work at android studio how to fix

Tags: android, eclipse

public class DemoWeBBrower {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    String answer = "A. hold - read";
     String answerQuestion = "";

     String[] arrStr1 = answer.split("\\.");
        String str1 = arrStr1[1];
            String[] Str2 = str1.split("-");
            answerQuestion = "Jeff _____ a book right now, he _____ a story to Linda.";
            for (int i = 1 ; i < Str2.length +1 ; i++){
                answerQuestion = answerQuestion.replaceFirst("_____",Str2[(i-1)]);
            }



                System.out.println( answerQuestion);


            }
   }
```

Where is problem? How can i fix it?

Comment: What does it have to do with android?

Comment: Provide details of what didn't work.

Comment: So, what doesn't work? Also, clean up your indentation.

Comment: I want to replace element "______" from string "Jeff _____ a book right now, he _____ a story to Linda." by  multiple elements what split from the String "A. hold - read" . I coded like above but it had not worked at android studio but it work at eclipse when i check.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 String answer = "A. hold - read";
 String answerQuestion = "";

 String[] arrStr1 = answer.split("\\.");
    String str1 = arrStr1[1];
        String[] Str2 = str1.split("-");
        answerQuestion = "Jeff _____ a book right now, he _____ a story to 
        Linda.";
        for (int i = 0; i < Str2.length(); i++){
            answerQuestion = answerQuestion.replaceFirst("_____",Str2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println( answerQuestion);
        }
```

}

Comment: it is worked! thanks so much bro! But i still not understand clear.

Comment: you foget '()' simvols in your code, but I don't know how it work on eclipse